Fillnodata with minimum height of surrounding pixels
I have a heightmap where water features such as lakes are nodata. The water level of these water features is unknown. I want to assume that the lowest surrounding value is of a shore and a good substitute for the water level.
With Fillnodata I can only fill the lakes with nearest neighbour or inverse distance weighting. Both methods results in different height values within one water feature. Smoothing results in a mean value, but in lakes with both a natural shore and a artifical broadwalk this can result in a water level that's higher than the actual shore.
Is there a way to find out the minimum value of all pixels touching a region of nodata and then to fill said region with that minimum value?

With existing GDAL and QGIS tools I think I would try using gdal_footprint for creating the lake polygons first. Or maybe you have such vector data already? Then expand the polygons by buffering, compute a difference buffered-original for getting a ring shaped polygon around the lake. Then with QGIS zonal statistics find the minimum height inside this shoreline ring, and finally take the lake polygon and burn with gdal_rasterize the height that you found into the DEM. Feels a bit complicated to me but if the question was "Is there a way?" I would say yes.
